# Git, create local branch (A) from two other branches (B and C) and then merge from A to B without C files

Tags: git

I develop Magento module and I have two repos first is my module and another is Magento itself. I clone my module repo to the directory then add Magento repo as a remote and merge two branches in one local branch called testing. It works fine.
But when developing I need both projects (module and Magento) open in editor so I edit code in  testing branch and then I need to commit that changes. But I can't just merge testing to module branch because I have Magento files in testing branch which I don't need in module branch.

Is there a way to merge changes from testing to module branch without files from magento branch?

Submodule and subtree didn't work because my branches overlaps their root directories, module is not just a subdirectory of magento branch.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear how your module and Magento are related. Is module a subdirectory of Magento?

Comment: It's several subdirectories in Magento root

Comment: maybe i am wrong, but to me this seems as a bad approach to branching strategy. Maybe you could have one "Module" branch from which you will  branch and merge back (to do features, fixes) on it, and at the end you can merge Module branch to TEST branch for testing

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to merge your testing branch to your module branch? Even though the Magento files won't be present after the merge you're seeking, all the Magento history will be inseparably linked to your module branch's history. That's probably not what you want.

If you really want a merge, you could either **write your own merge strategy or use `git merge --no-commit`**, manually delete the files of Magento you don't want in your module branch and commit the resulting merge. If manual deletion is too much work, you could use `git revert -n -m1 <unwanted-merge-id>` instead.

The cleaner solution I suggest is **cherry-pick and recreate the testing branch**. You always merge Magento branches into your testing branch, I assume you have no other merges inside testing.

This cherry-picks (copies to the current branch) list of non-merge commits from testing branch since its common ancestor with the current branch:

```
git rev-list --reverse --first-parent --no-merges ..testing | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

Then you can get rid of the old testing branch as it contains unnecessary merges and its contents is otherwise the same as the one of your module branch. You can start it again on top of your module branch. From your testing branch call `git reset --hard module` – but make sure you have no uncommited changes beforehand, because they would be lost!